# MYSQL SUM() isnt adding correctly

Tags: mysql

Well I guess I shouldn't say it isn't adding correctly, but more like the SUM() function is not producing the results I am expecting to get. The problem I have is with a table that tracks hours for employees.

Here is the data from the table:

```
table name = labor_table
employee_id | labor_date | hours
252         | 2015-04-30 | 8
252         | 2015-05-01 | 8
252         | 2015-05-04 | 8
252         | 2015-05-24 | 0.2
```

So if I run this query on that table

```
SELECT employee_id, 
    SUM(`hours`) AS hours
FROM (`labor_table`) 
WHERE `employee_id` = '252'    
GROUP BY employee_id
```

I get the Following result:

```
employee_id | hours
252         | 24.200000002980232
```

Can anyone tell me why this is happening?
the field "hours" is set as a FLOAT, could that be the reason for the extra digits?

Comment: Yes.You've decided to store hours as floats rather than decimals

Comment: Not necessarily a bad choice. But you have to live with the consequences.

Comment: That was the only thing I could think of but see the extra decimal places do not always go out that far. Sometimes its what I would expect like 24.2 and other times its like I describe above 24.200000755. I guess best thing to do  is set the field as a decimal?

Comment: Set two decimal points for the field `hours` e.g.  Float(xx,2)

Comment: [What every programmer should know about Floating Point numbers](http://floating-point-gui.de/).  Use `CAST(SUM(hours) AS DECIMAL(7,2))` for example.

Comment: Samir Float(xx, 2) still is not a good fix as the result can end up being 25.4 which is even worse. Since the hours field is later used to calculate wages I think I am going to have to change it to a decimal field.  Thanks bishop for the link a very well explained website.